# Change thel position of axis labels and show more ticks on the axis

Tags: plotting

I need to change the position of my axes labels such that the y-axis label is in the middle and parallel to the y-axis. Also, show the ticks 1000 in the axis, as shown in the picture. 
Here is my code:

```
p1 = 
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 1000}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1000},
    PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Thickness[0.01]},
    PlotLegends -> {Style["Standard", 20]}];

p2 = 
  Plot[x^10/1000^9, {x, 0, 1000}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1000},
    PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.9, 0, 0], Thickness[0.01]},
    PlotLegends -> {Style["n=10", 20]}];

Show[p1, p2, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontColor -> Black},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  Arrowheads[0.04]],
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]],
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  AxesLabel -> {"ρ", "f(ρ)"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think this gives you pretty much everything you asked for.

```
Labeled[
  Plot[{x, x^10/1000^9}, {x, 0, 1000},
    PlotRange -> {0, 1000},
    PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, 125}, {20, 200}},
    PlotStyle ->
      {Directive[RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Thickness[0.01]], 
       Directive[RGBColor[0.9, 0, 0], Thickness[0.01]]},
    AxesStyle -> 
      Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Arrowheads[Automatic]], 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
    PlotLegends -> {Style["Standard", 20], Style["n = 10", 20]},
    ImageSize -> 450],
  {Style["ρ", 20, Bold], Style["f(ρ)", 20, Bold]}, {Bottom, Left}]
```

[image: plot]

However, I think the plot would look better if custom ticks were used as well and if the axis arrows thickness were visually balanced.

```
ticks =
  {Table[{x, x, {.015, 0}}, {x, 200, 1000, 200}],
   Table[{y, y, {.015, 0}}, {y, 200, 1000, 200}]};

arrows =
  {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Arrowheads[Automatic]],
   Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Arrowheads[Automatic]]};

Labeled[
  Plot[{x, x^10/1000^9}, {x, 0, 1000},
    PlotRange -> {0, 1000},
    PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, 125}, {20, 200}},
    PlotStyle ->
      {Directive[RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Thickness[0.01]], 
       Directive[RGBColor[0.9, 0, 0], Thickness[0.01]]},
    AxesStyle -> arrows,
    Ticks -> ticks, 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
    PlotLegends -> {Style["Standard", 20], Style["n = 10", 20]},
    ImageSize -> 500],
  {Style["ρ", 20, Bold], Style["f(ρ)", 20, Bold]}, {Bottom, Left}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes, I am woking on it, Thank you very much, the second one looks better.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
Plot[{x, x^10/1000^9}, {x, 0, 1000}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 1000}}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.01]},{Red, Thickness[0.01]}} 
PlotLegends -> {Style["Standard", 20], Style["n=10", 20]}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Rho]", 14], Style["f(\[Rho])", 14]}, 
RotateLabel -> False, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, Get it. Thanks a lot.